# Prevent Zsh from escaping newlines

Tags: macos, bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using Oh My Zsh on OS X. I'm trying to write an autocomplete function that outputs my combined `tmux` and `tmuxinator` sessions.

Here's what my autocomplete function looks like:

```
tmux-and-tmuxinator-sessions-autofill() {
  reply=$( tmux-and-tmuxinator-sessions )
}

compctl -K tmux-and-tmuxinator-sessions-autofill ta
```

`tmux-and-tmuxinator-sessions` outputs the following:

```
dotfiles
landonschropp.com
something
something_else
```

However, If I type `ta` and hit tab, I get:

```
ta dotfiles$'\n'landonschropp.com$'\n'something$'\n'something_else
```

I'm pretty new to Zsh, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reply` should be an array, not a single string.

```
tmux-and-tmuxinator-sessions-autofill() {
  reply=( $(tmux-and-tmuxinator-sessions) )
}
```